# Find a executable file path programmatically and fast

Tags: java, file, path

I want to find a .exe files path programatically in Java, for example:

- Skype.exe is entered into a program to find the direct path to it
- Program does an algorithm that finds the file path
- Program returns the file path C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Skype.exe

A method I have tried is sorting through the systems files until "skype.exe" is found, but that takes up a lot of time and resources.

Is there any hack that could make it almost instant, like maybe a Win_Api function/cmd command or is sorting through the file system until the program is found the only way?

Comment: Prioritizing common locations of executables might help speed this up on the average system. Other than that I have nothing.

Comment: The only way I can think of this being done in a timely fashion is use [Jawin](http://jawinproject.sourceforge.net/) to interface with Windows libraries and then implement something akin to the "Start Menu" search feature that operates on recently accessed files and short-cuts present in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`. Might even be able to do so with using Windows libraries. More research is necessary of course.

Comment: Are looking for any `exe` files, or would a solution that very quickly finds "installed" `exe` files suffice?

Comment: That could actually work, going through installed exe's

Comment: Start looking in the PATH.

Answer (score 2):

I actually found something that works, albeit not the fastest but only takes around 100ms - 500ms to do depending on the exe.

You need to use a runtime process to do this.

Basically you go into the root of your drive, and then search the filesystem using these commands in the cmd.

```
cd \
dir /s /b mytool.exe
```

This will return the filepath.

My code for it:

(Hackish I know)

```
try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./res/getPrograms.bat " + exeName);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while(true) {
            line = input.readLine();
            if(line == null) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And the .bat file (I am passing the parameter "eclipse.exe" to the bat file which is represented as %1):

```
cd \
dir /s /b %1
exit
```

The output becomes:

```
C:\Users\Mitchell\workspace\Remote Admin>cd \ 

C:\>dir /s /b eclipse.exe 
C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

As an extension to [@Minor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20624976/2081889), if you wanted to increase performance by limiting search to only programs that are currently "installed" on Windows, the following registry keys contain information on "installed" programs.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Using powershell, you can access properties of installed software stored in these keys. Of particular interest is the `InstallLocation` property.

Then, you just modify your Java code to utilise another batch script that retrieves these install locations, and specifically target these install locations for `exe` files.

**getInstalledPrograms.bat**

```
@echo off
powershell -Command "Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -match \"%1\"} | Select-Object -Property InstallLocation"
exit
```

**getPrograms.bat**

```
@echo off
cd %1
dir /b /s "*%2*.exe"
exit
```

**Java Example:**

```
String search = "skype";
try {
    Process getInstalled = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./src/getInstalledPrograms.bat " + search);
    BufferedReader installed = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getInstalled.getInputStream()));
    String install;
    String exe;
    int count = 0;
    while(true) {
        install = installed.readLine();
        if(install == null) {
            break;
        }
        install = install.trim();
        // Ignore powershell table header and newlines.
        if(count < 3 || install.equals("")) {
            count++;
            continue;
        }
        Process getExes = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./src/getPrograms.bat " + "\"" + install + "\"");
        BufferedReader exes = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getExes.getInputStream()));
        while(true) {
            exe = exes.readLine();
            if(exe == null) {
                break;
            }
            exe = exe.trim();
            System.out.println(exe);
        }
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Currently my Java example duplicates `InstallLocation` returned by getInstalledPrograms.bat, although the script works fine in cmd. Conceptually though, this solution is sound.

Comment: thanks but I get Get-ItemProperty : Specified cast is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know WHICH executable is being executed from the command line when you type .  Use the which/where commands..

Unix/linux/Mac OSX Possix
<**which**>

which chmod
which cd
which ls
which myprogram

returns  returns nothing if no such program file exists.

for Windows use where
<**where**> /?       for help on this command

If you don't have an executable but an alias or some sort of environment function/procedure/shell command..   use the <**type**> command on Unix/linux/Mac OS X.    That will tell yo if you are dealing with an alias, environment function, or executable.